# While using request.urlretrieve of python ,certificate verify failed on mac system's pycham

Tags: python, nsurl

When I use request.urlretrieve of python, the error certificate verify failed will occur, which just only appears on mac. I have tried to use some way to solve , such as install the latest certitficate and update the certificate , it's useless.
If you have any suggestion, I will all try to do.
That's all , it's my honor for you reading.Thank you!!!
[Code Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmVJj.png)

Test code:

```
import json
from urllib import request
import requests


def douyu(page=1):
    url = "https://www.douyu.com/gapi/rknc/directory/yzRec/{page}"

    
    dic = json.loads(res.text)
    # print(dic)

    
    meizi_list = dic['data']['rl']
    print(meizi_list)
    for meizi in meizi_list:
        nn = meizi['nn']
        rs1 = meizi['rs1']
        # print(nn,rs1)

        request.urlretrieve(rs1, f"{nn}.png")
        print(nn, "work done")

douyu(1)
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your suggestion. And I have solve this problem , on mac system, we need to uopdate the certiifcal by ourselves . 
cd /Applications , After this , you will watch Install Certificates.command,double onclick on this to run it , you will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

On mac system, we need to uopdate the certiifcal by ourselves .
cd /Applications , After this , you will watch Install Certificates.command,double onclick on this to run it , you will succeed.
[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtCgw.png)